# Default float format for pandas.to_csv()?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to set a default float format for Pandas so that I don't have to specify it every time I save a file (like following)? Thanks.

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', float_format='%.3f')
```

Comment: Can't you extend pandas and override the behavior for that specific part?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't by design.
Why won't you write a function for that.